# Bootstrap typeahead autocomplete from multiple sources?

Tags: jquery, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

Using Bootstrap Typeahead script, I'd like to make an input box with autocompletion.
The input box is:

```
<input type="text" class="input-medium search-query" id="name" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off">
```

I have JSON data whose simple version is like this:

```
var name_list = {
  "first" = ["John", "Jonathan", "Tom"],
  "last" = ["James", "Smith", "Bush"]
}
```

And when things are typed in the text box, now I show the list only from "first."

```
$('#name').typeahead({source: name_list.first);
```

But I'd like to show the names from "last" too. For example, if I type "j" I want to see

```
John
Jonathan
(ideally with a divide line from Bootstrap css)
James
```

in the autocompletion list. 
How can I do this? Is there any way to call multiple JSON data sources?

Comment: you could transform your datas and join the 2 arrays before it is displayed , there is a callback you can hook in typeahead.

Comment: @mpm I can't simply merge into one array, since the action is different according to the source..

Comment: yet typeahead is not concerned with what happens next if remember well , it will just display the word when you click on it. you can also change your data structure to a tuple , first element the name , second the type ( value ,  firstname | lastname ) , display only the value and with the updater callback set a data-value-type=firstname|lastname on the input , so when you click on whatever you need to click you can know wether it is a lastname or a first name

Comment: @mpm you should make that an answer